# Реализация класса контейнера

Tags: c++

Всем доброго времени суток. Возник вопрос по выполнению задания. Вот само задание:

Необходимо разработать класс контейнера, реализующий приведенный ниже интерфейс. При разработке допускается использовать STL.

```
class ElemNotFound {};
template < class ElemType, class IndexType > class IContainer
{
public:
   virtual const ElemType& GetElem( const IndexType& index ) const throw ( ElemNotFound ) = 0;
   virtual void PutElem( const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem ) throw () = 0;
};
```

Решение надо представить под Windows и Linux.

Выполнил задание, однако отказали, не подскажете в чем косяк ?

```
template < class ElemType, class IndexType >
class CContainer: public IContainer<ElemType, IndexType>, public map <IndexType, ElemType>
{
public:
    inline const ElemType& GetElem( const IndexType& index ) const throw ( ElemNotFound ) {
        map<IndexType, ElemType>::const_iterator toRet = find(index);
        if (toRet == end()) {
            throw ElemNotFound();
        }

        return toRet->second;
     }

     inline void PutElem( const IndexType& index, const ElemType& elem ) throw () {
        insert(make_pair(index,elem));
     }
};
```

Comment: Отказавший должен был мотивировать свое решение.

Comment: @андрей коломяга, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не нравится наследование от `map`. "Предпочитайте агрегацию наследованию".

Внутри `CContainer` следует завести `map`, а не наследоваться от него.

Касательно самого наследования, почему наследование от `map` открытое?